# SED: Replacing String After Single Quote

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file named `file.txt` that contains the following:

```
CREATE LARGE TABLESPACE LONGSPCE1 IN DATABASE PARTITION GROUP IBMDEFAULTGROUP PAGESIZE 4096 MANAGED BY DATABASE
     USING (FILE '/db2data1/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c1' 1588368,
            FILE '/db2data2/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c2' 1588368,
            FILE '/db2data3/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c3' 1588368,
            FILE '/db2data4/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c4' 1588368)
```

I am trying to change the numerics after  the `c[0-9]'` to a value of 100.

I have tried the following with no luck.

```
cat file.txt |sed 's/(c1'' )\([0-9]*\)/$1 100/g'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed "s/\(c[0-9]\+'\) [0-9]\+/\1 100/" file.txt

USING (FILE '/db2data1/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c1' 100,
       FILE '/db2data2/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c2' 100,
       FILE '/db2data3/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c3' 100,
       FILE '/db2data4/TGT_INST/TGT_DB/LONGSPCE1.c4' 100)
```